# Find Label Control in Repeater Asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater

I am using repeater and I want to find the label control in my repeater. here is my code

```
 <asp:Repeater ID="friendRepeater" runat="server">

    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">

    <ItemTemplate>
    <tr style=" width:700px; height:120px;">
       <td>
       <div style=" padding-left:180px;"> 
           <div id="leftHandPost" style="float:left; width:120px; height:120px; border: medium solid #cdaf95; padding-top:5px;">
              <div id="childLeft" style=" padding-left:5px;">
                 <div id="photo"  style=" border: thin solid black; width:100px;height:100px;">
                   <asp:Image id="photoImage" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# String.Concat("Images/", Eval("Picture")) %>' Width="100px" Height="100px" />
                 </div>
               </div><!--childLeft-->
            </div><!--leftHandPost-->
            </div>
        </td>

                        <td>
                            <div id="rightHandPost" style=" float:right; padding-right:260px;">
                                <div id="childRight" style="width:400px; height:120px; border: medium solid #cdaf95; padding-top:5px; padding-left:10px;">
                                    <strong><asp:Label id="lblName" runat="server"><%# Eval("PersonName") %></asp:Label></strong><br />
                                    <div style=" float:right; padding-right:10px;"><asp:Button runat="server" Text="Add" onClick="add" /></div><br />
                                    <asp:Label id="lblID" runat="server"><%# Eval("PersonID") %></asp:Label><br />
                                    <asp:Label id="lblEmail" runat="server"><%# Eval("Email") %></asp:Label>
                                </div><!--childRight-->
                            </div><!--rightHandPost-->
                        </td>
                    </tr>

    </ItemTemplate>

    <AlternatingItemTemplate>
     <tr style=" width:700px; height:120px;">
       <td>
       <div style=" padding-left:180px;"> 
           <div id="Div1" style="float:left; width:120px; height:120px; border: medium solid #cdaf95; padding-top:5px;">
              <div id="Div2" style="padding-left:5px;">
                 <div id="Div3"  style=" border: thin solid black; width:100px;height:100px;">
                   <asp:Image id="photoImage" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# String.Concat("Images/", Eval("Picture")) %>' Width="100px" Height="100px" />
                 </div>
               </div><!--childLeft-->
            </div><!--leftHandPost-->
        </div>
        </td>

                        <td>
                            <div id="Div4" style=" float:right; padding-right:260px;">
                                <div id="Div5" style="width:400px; height:120px; border: medium solid #cdaf95; padding-top:5px; padding-left:10px;">
                                    <strong><asp:Label id="lblName" runat="server"><%# Eval("PersonName")%></asp:Label></strong>
                                    <div style=" float:right; padding-right:10px;"><asp:Button id="btnAdd" runat="server" Text="Add" onClick="add"></asp:Button></div><br />
                                    <br />
                                    <asp:Label id="lblID" runat="server"><%# Eval("PersonID") %></asp:Label><br />
                                    <asp:Label id="lblEmail" runat="server"><%# Eval("Email") %></asp:Label>
                                </div><!--childRight-->
                            </div><!--rightHandPost-->
                        </td>
                    </tr>
    </AlternatingItemTemplate>

    <FooterTemplate>
    </table>
    </FooterTemplate>

</asp:Repeater>
```

Here is the code behind for the add button.

```
protected void add(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {           
        DateTime date = DateTime.Now;
        System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label la = (System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label)friendRepeater.FindControl("PersonID");
        String id = la.Text;

        try
        {
           MySqlConnection connStr = new MySqlConnection();
           connStr.ConnectionString = "Server = localhost; Database = healthlivin; Uid = root; Pwd = khei92;";
           String insertFriend = "INSERT INTO contactFriend(friendID, PersonID, PersonIDB, date) values (@id, @personIDA, @personIDB, @date)";
           MySqlCommand cmdInsertStaff = new MySqlCommand(insertFriend, connStr);
           cmdInsertStaff.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", "F000004");
           cmdInsertStaff.Parameters.AddWithValue("@personIDA", "M000001");
           cmdInsertStaff.Parameters.AddWithValue("@personIDB", id);
           cmdInsertStaff.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", date);
           connStr.Open();
           cmdInsertStaff.ExecuteNonQuery();

           MessageBox.Show("inserted");
           connStr.Close();

         }
         catch (Exception ex)
         {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
         }            
    }
```

I have get the error of Object reference not set to an instance of an object. I think is because there are no value in the Label. The Find Control are not working. May I know how can fix this problem? Thank you very much

Comment: You should use the `CommandName` and `CommandArgument` instead of trying to retreive your value from a label.

Comment: ok... I get your mean and idea. I will try and see. Thx :D

Answer (score 8):

```
foreach (RepeaterItem item in friendRepeater.Items)
{
   Label lab = item.FindControl("lblName") as Label;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you can use this:

```
var personId= (Label)friendRepeater.Items[0].FindControl("PersonID");
```

Comment: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: I think your problem is not for find a control\

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you don't have any Label names "personID", so it couldn't find that control.

I assume that you want to get value from this line

```
<asp:Label id="lblID" runat="server"><%# Eval("PersonID") %></asp:Label>
```

And this Label control names "lblID", so your query code should be

```
System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label la = (System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label)friendRepeater.FindControl("lblID");
```

Use **lblID** to find control instead of **PersonID**

Comment: Opps... I have make a mistake.. I have change it but there are no value insert to database but there are no error. May I know more about it?

Comment: This method **cmdInsertStaff.ExecuteNonQuery();** should return number of affected rows, you should check the return value if it's more than zoro or not, if not that mean your connected command to mySQL has problem. Please also put breakpoint and debug to check all values you want to insert.

Comment: ERhmm~~ So sorry I can't get your mean. Can explain further? Thank you very much.

Comment: First, you have to check all values at runtime if they are correct, for this case I mean the id value which you get from PersonID field. Then you should modify this line **cmdInsertStaff.ExecuteNonQuery();** to be **int rowAffected = cmdInsertStaff.ExecuteNonQuery();**, and check the rowAffected value, if it more than 0 that mean your insert code is complete. But if not that mean your insert code has problem.

Comment: I don't know the whole of your project structure, but it could be many reasons that made you couldn't insert data to database. If you're so sure that your connection string correct and could connect to database, then the problem is your insert command, and data field permission in database.

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me.

Label lblperson = (Label)(rpfrndRepeater.Items[0]).FindControl("lblPerson");