# I have Added 2 ASP Image controls, but just one showing in C#(.cs) page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have added 2 image controls.

```
<asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" />
<asp:Image ID="Image2" runat="server" />
```

[image: Compile time error on Image1 control]

[image: Image2 control in design page]

[image: Image1 control in design page]

But The problem is, just Image1 is detecting in server page .cs,  I am developing an Forum page, where 1 image control will hold commentator image, and another will be hold after comment commentator image. I use Repeater control, Can anyone help me regarding this ?

Comment: By looking at the images, the control Image1 is not nested and Image2 is nested within a repeater which you cannot directly access in server side code. You have to use FindControl as discussed here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19872148/find-label-control-in-repeater-asp-net

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find Label Control in Repeater Asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19872148/find-label-control-in-repeater-asp-net)